# Java: Get static child Class

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I have the following Scenatio:
I have a Hibernate Data Entity Class:

```
public class Home extends BaseDatabaseEntity {
    @Id
    private long id;
}
```

that extends my Base Entity:

```
public abstract class BaseDatabaseEntity {
    public static <T extends BaseDatabaseEntity> T getById(Class<T> clazz, Serializable id) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            @Cleanup Session session = HibernateConfigurator.getSessionFactory().openSession();

            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            T returner = session.get(clazz, id);
            transaction.commit();
            return returner;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

To retrieve the Object from my Database, i use:

```
Home.getById(Home.class, 1);
```

My Goal is to get rid of the Home.class / don't need it in the constructor

Comment: `Home getHomeClassById( int id ) { return Home.getById( Home.class, id ); }`

Comment: This is not a constructor, but a static method. --- I do not think that it is possible to remove the `Class<T>` parameter while preserving type safety.

Comment: Bit of a code smell - static methods are not "truly" inherited (they're allowed for convenience). You can "overload" the method (without changing the name) within `Home` however like so: `static Home getById(int id) { return BaseDatabaseEntity.getById(Home.class, id); }` (a bit similar to @markspace's suggestion). In this sense, each class would be responsible for providing the type internally, allowing you to forgo it externally. I would also make the `BaseDatabaseEntity#getById` into a `protected` method, as it would be awkward to allow `Home.getById(NotAHome.class, 1);`

Comment: @Rouge thank you, this might be my solution, if it can't be achived in another way.